# postfix is unable to receive emails from some domains

Tags: postfix, email-server

I am running a postfix/dovecot email server. The OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I am also using aws as relayhost to send emails as port 25 is blocked. It is working fine except I am not able to receive emails from some domains such as amazon or one of my hosting provider. Other domains such as gmail or outlook are working fine. Any idea why this is happening?

Below is my postfix config.

```
##
## Network settings
##

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain

# Enable auth
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# Set username and password
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:aws-username:aws-password
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# Turn on tls encryption 
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
# Set external SMTP relay host here IP or hostname accepted along with a port number. 
relayhost = email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:587


##
## Mail queue settings
##

maximal_queue_lifetime = 1h
bounce_queue_lifetime = 1h
maximal_backoff_time = 15m
minimal_backoff_time = 5m
queue_run_delay = 5m


##
## TLS settings
###

tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA


### Outbound SMTP connections (Postfix as sender)

#smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_tls_policy_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/tls-policy.cf
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt


### Inbound SMTP connections

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem


##
## Local mail delivery to Dovecot via LMTP
##

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp


##
## Spam filter and DKIM signatures via Rspamd
##

smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:11332
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:11332
milter_protocol = 6
milter_mail_macros =  i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
milter_default_action = accept



##
## Server Restrictions for clients, cecipients and relaying
## (concerning S2S-connections. Mailclient-connections are configured in submission-section in master.cf)
##

### Conditions in which Postfix works as a relay. (for mail user clients)
smtpd_relay_restrictions =      reject_non_fqdn_recipient
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain
                                permit_mynetworks
                                reject_unauth_destination


### Conditions in which Postfix accepts e-mails as recipient (additional to relay conditions)
### check_recipient_access checks if an account is "sendonly"
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/recipient-access.cf


### Restrictions for all sending foreign servers ("SMTP clients")
smtpd_client_restrictions =     permit_mynetworks
                                check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/without_ptr
                                reject_unknown_client_hostname


### Foreign mail servers must present a valid "HELO"
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =   permit_mynetworks
                            reject_invalid_helo_hostname
                            reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
                            reject_unknown_helo_hostname

# Block clients, which start sending too early
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining


##
## Restrictions for MUAs (Mail user agents)
##

mua_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_sender_login_mismatch,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject


##
## Postscreen Filter
##

### Postscreen Whitelist / Blocklist
postscreen_access_list =        permit_mynetworks
                                cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop


# Drop connections if other server is sending too quickly
postscreen_greet_action = drop


### DNS blocklists
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =    ix.dnsbl.manitu.net*2
                            zen.spamhaus.org*2
postscreen_dnsbl_action = drop


##
## MySQL queries
##

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/accounts.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/domains.cf
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps


##
## Miscellaneous
##

### Maximum mailbox size (0=unlimited - is already limited by Dovecot quota)
mailbox_size_limit = 0

### Maximum size of inbound e-mails (50 MB)
message_size_limit = 52428800

### Do not notify system users on new e-mail
biff = no

### Users always have to provide full e-mail addresses
append_dot_mydomain = no

### Delimiter for "Address Tagging"
recipient_delimiter = +
```

This is the log of one such domain from where I am not receiving any email.

```
Jun  3 13:29:36 mail postfix/smtpd[8301]: connect from mx01.simplyhosting.cloud[91.186.2.150]
Jun  3 13:29:37 mail postfix/smtpd[8301]: 76948C00234: client=mx01.simplyhosting.cloud[91.186.2.150]
Jun  3 13:34:37 mail postfix/smtpd[8301]: timeout after DATA (0 bytes) from mx01.simplyhosting.cloud[91.186.2.150]
Jun  3 13:34:37 mail postfix/smtpd[8301]: disconnect from mx01.simplyhosting.cloud[91.186.2.150] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=0/1 commands=3/4
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved. I found the remote smtp server in question is not able to send any data. It's just dropping connection after handshaking. Once I added *net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0* in /etc/sysctl.conf, I started getting emails from those said domains.

Update: Forgot to mention, I needed to adjust the default MTU size of the server machine to 1492 which I found by pinging google dns servers.